# How to get list of inline or multi statement table, value functions related to a table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-functions

How to get the list of inline or Multi statement table value functions related to a table in SQL server?

The below code doesnot give the answer:

```
select * from sys.objects where name like '%tblfunction1%'
```

Comment: Improved question.

Comment: i have defined a multi statement table value function that joins multi table toghether. i want in one of joined tables find this table value function and output column of this table value function with tsql.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
EXEC sys.sp_depends @objname = N'dbo.tfn_FunctionName';
```